# JavaScript for monetary values?

Tags: javascript

I have this function to format monetary values:

```
function formatMonetary(v){   
   v = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
   v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{15})$/,"$1.$2");
   v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{11})$/,"$1.$2");
   v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{8})$/,"$1.$2");
   v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{5})$/,"$1.$2");
   v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1,$2");
   return v;   
}
```

When I input just a number `1` or `1,1` this function assume the value:

`0,01`

`0,11`

With a value alignment in the right way, is possible this function assume a value in the left way, when I input a number `1` or `1,1` :

`1,00`

`1,10`

Comment: 1. No need of `{1}` in the regex when you want to select only one digit, you can use `\d` 2. You can chain the `replace` methods

Comment: Are you trying to simply add two decimal characters to all numbers?

Comment: Yes Daniel, if I input 1, I want 1,00, if I input 1,1 I want 1,10

Comment: "*With a value alignment in the right way, is possible this function assume a value in the left way*" – what does this mean?

Comment: Thanks David, assuming I use number 9, this function returns 0,09, I want if I use number 9 this function returns 9,00

Comment: Edson, when I use it with a number, e.g. `formatMonetary(9);`, I get a type error. If I use it with a string, `formatMonetary('9');`, I get back `"9"`.

Comment: That is, I wanted this function to complete me decimals 1 = 1.00 2 = 2.00

Comment: Use `.toFixed(2)`. Or even better, consult the most upvoted answer on the duplicate; it has the complete code for the transformation you need.